I got error when I want to use a custom hook for getting data from useContext
I got this error:

Exported variable ‘useAuth’ has or is using name ‘AuthcontextType’ from external module “c:/Users/PC/Desktop/my practices/react-course-part2-starter/src/state-management/Contexts/authContext” but cannot be named.ts(4023)
const useAuth: () => AuthcontextType

when I want to run the code in this file:
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../Contexts/authContext";

const useAuth = () =>  useContext(AuthContext);

export default useAuth

This is my AuthContext file:
import React, { Dispatch } from "react";
import { authAction } from "../Reducers/authReducer";

interface AuthcontextType {
    user:string,
    dispatch:Dispatch<authAction>
}

const AuthContext= React.createContext<AuthcontextType> ({} as AuthcontextType)

export default AuthContext

Does anyone know how I could solve this?
